clearkey drm with exoplayer playback error
i am trying to play the clearkey drm stream in my android app using media3 exoplayer library. code is showing no error but when i am trying to launch the app it is giving these 2 exceptions:
first one is this:

DRM session error
androidx.media3.exoplayer.drm.MediaDrmCallbackException: androidx.media3.datasource.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: data

second is this:

Playback error
androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:736)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:690)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: androidx.media3.exoplayer.drm.DrmSession$DrmSessionException: androidx.media3.exoplayer.drm.MediaDrmCallbackException: androidx.media3.datasource.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: data

this is my whole code:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private PlayerView playerView;
private ExoPlayer player;

// ClearKey DRM Information
private static final String STREAM_URL = "https://live4.shoq.com.pk/live/eds/PTV_Sports/DASH/PTV_Sports.mpd?|drmScheme=clearkey&drmLicense=9ecad6c4413f8bdc54712ce6c072a2cf:442df559c369bdada8ba3abe97811575";
private static final String DRM_KEY_ID = "9ecad6c4413f8bdc54712ce6c072a2cf";
private static final String DRM_KEY = "442df559c369bdada8ba3abe97811575";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the content view to your layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialize the PlayerView
    playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);

    // Initialize the ExoPlayer
    initializePlayer();
}

private void initializePlayer() {
    // Create a new ExoPlayer instance
    player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();

    // Bind the player to the view
    playerView.setPlayer(player);

    // Build the MediaItem with DRM configuration for ClearKey
    MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder()
            .setUri(Uri.parse(STREAM_URL)) // Stream URL
            .setDrmConfiguration(new MediaItem.DrmConfiguration.Builder(C.CLEARKEY_UUID)  // ClearKey UUID
                    .setLicenseUri("data:application/json;base64," + getClearKeyLicense()) // License in base64
                    .build())
            .build();

    // Set the MediaItem to the player
    player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);

    // Prepare the player
    player.prepare();

    // Start playback automatically
    player.play();
}

/**
 * Generates the ClearKey license in base64-encoded JSON format.
 *
 * @return Base64-encoded license string.
 */
private String getClearKeyLicense() {
    // ClearKey requires the license to be in JSON format with keys array
    String jsonLicense = "{"
            + "\"keys\": [{"
            + "\"kty\": \"oct\","
            + "\"kid\": \"" + DRM_KEY_ID + "\","
            + "\"k\": \"" + DRM_KEY + "\""
            + "}],"
            + "\"type\": \"temporary\""
            + "}";

    // Encode the JSON license to base64
    return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(jsonLicense.getBytes(), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (player == null) {
        initializePlayer();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (player != null) {
        player.play();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (player != null) {
        player.pause();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    releasePlayer();
}

/**
 * Releases the ExoPlayer instance.
 */
private void releasePlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
}

}
what am i doing wrong in this? even i tested the stream link in jwplayer and its working very fine but in the app it is giving these exceptions
